# Add a second button to a Firefox extension using jpm

Tags: firefox-addon

Is it possible to add a second button to this Firefox extension:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

var button = ActionButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    icon: {
      "16": "./icon-16.png",
      "32": "./icon-32.png",
      "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: firstClick
  });

function firstClick(state) {
      button.on("click", firstClick);
      tabs.activeTab.url = "url";
      tabs.activeTab.reload();
}
```

Well that's that. I'd like to know if I can add two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this part for sure:

```
let myPanel = ActionButton({
   ....
})

let { getActiveView }=require("sdk/view/core");
let myPanelView = getActiveView(myPanel);
```

Then you have to add the style of `chromeclass-toolbar-additional` somewhere into the DOM of it. Try adding it straight to the obtained element:

```
myPanelView.classList.add('chromeclass-toolbar-additional');
```